# conversion from valid Object to Bitmap reults in null c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, null

I am trying to use threads to process multiple images parallel to each other. In the code you'll see that I give the mehtod 'imgprocessing' a bitmap, but image processing recieves only object parameters. so I have to type-cast it to bitmap, and at some point it throws the exception: "Parameter is not valid'. Apperently, bitmap becomes a null at some point.
it only happens after a few threads had already done the processing.
**Question is: why during the type-cast is my bitmap null ? I have no idea why would it stop casting it normally.**
code-
main:

```
 int i = 0;
            float[] percentcount = new float[6];
            string[] sc = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\gn clouds-snow", "*.jpg");
            Bitmap[] bt = new Bitmap[sc.Length];
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[sc.Length];
            foreach (string file in sc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("number of image: " + i + " / " + sc.Length);
                bt[i] = new Bitmap(file);
                threads[i] = new Thread(imgProcessing);
                threads[i].Start(bt[i]);
                i++;
            }

            foreach(Thread thread in threads)
            {
                thread.Join();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("highest snow percent:" + ((double)maxgray / sc.Length) * 100);
            Console.WriteLine("lowest:" + (((double)maxwhite) / sc.Length) * 100);
```

imgprocessing function:

```
private static void imgProcessing(Object obj1)
        {
            Bitmap bt = new Bitmap((Image)obj1); //exception occurs here
            //Bitmap //ft = new Bitmap(bt);
            Color color = new Color();
            Ipn[] Iparams = new Ipn[6];
            int nm = 2211840;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            //int holder = 0;
            float hue = 0;
            float brt = 0;
            float sat = 0;
            GiveId(Iparams);

                for (i = 0; i < bt.Height; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < bt.Width; j++)
                    {
                        color = bt.GetPixel(j, i);
                        hue = color.GetHue();
                        sat = color.GetSaturation();
                        brt = color.GetBrightness();
                        #region if statements
                        //white
                        if (brt > 0.7)
                        {
                            Iparams[5].Percent++;
                            //ft.SetPixel(j,i,Color.White);
                        }

                        //gray
                        else if (sat <= 0.25)
                        {
                            Iparams[4].Percent++;
                            //ft.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Gray);
                        }
                        //black
                        else if (color.R <= 15 && color.G <= 15 && color.B <= 15 && brt < 0.3)
                        {
                            Iparams[3].Percent++;
                            //ft.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Black);
                        } 

                        //red
                        else if (hue > 0 && hue <= 59)
                        {
                            Iparams[0].Percent++;
                            //ft.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Red);
                        }
                        //green 
                        else if (hue > 60 && hue <= 150)
                        {
                            Iparams[1].Percent++;
                            //ft.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Green);
                        }

                        //blue
                        else if (hue > 150 && hue <= 270)
                        {
                            Iparams[2].Percent++;
                            //ft.SetPixel(j, i, Color.Blue);
                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                }


                for (k = 0; k < Iparams.Length; k++)
                {
                    Iparams[k].Percent = ((float)Iparams[k].Percent / nm) * 100;
                }

                //bubblesort(Iparams);

                lock (lockobject)
                {
                    #region space code
                    //calculate the color percentages for each color

                    //if (Iparams[0].ID == ID.gray && Iparams[1].ID == ID.blue)
                    //{
                    //    counter2++;
                    //}
                    //else if (Iparams[1].ID == ID.white && Iparams[0].ID == ID.blue)
                    //{
                    //    counter1++;
                    //}
                    #endregion

                    #region ocean code
                    //if (Iparams[0].ID == ID.blue)
                    //{
                    //    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter1);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter2);

                    //holder = (int)(Iparams[0].Percent - Iparams[1].Percent);
                    //Interlocked.Add(ref dis, holder);
                    #endregion

                    ////ft.Save(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\results\" + name + ".jpg");
                    //Interlocked.Increment(ref name);
                    #region veg code
                    //if (Iparams[0].ID == ID.green)
                    //{
                    //    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter1);
                    //    holder = (int)(Iparams[0].Percent - Iparams[1].Percent);
                    //    Interlocked.Add(ref dis, holder);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //    Interlocked.Increment(ref counter2);
                    #endregion 
                    #region snow&clouds code
                    /*understanding what is the highest percentages of white and gray and the lowest.
                     * 
                     */
                    double graypercent = Convert.ToDouble(Iparams[4].Percent);
                    double whitepercent = Convert.ToDouble(Iparams[5].Percent);
                    if(Iparams[4].Percent > maxgray)
                    {
                        Interlocked.Exchange(ref maxgray, graypercent);
                    }
                    else if(Iparams[4].Percent < mingray)
                    {
                        Interlocked.Exchange(ref mingray, graypercent);
                    }

                    if(Iparams[5].Percent > maxwhite)
                    {
                        Interlocked.Exchange(ref maxwhite, Iparams[5].Percent);
                    }
                    else if(Iparams[5].Percent < minwhite)
                    {
                        Interlocked.Exchange(ref minwhite, Iparams[5].Percent);
                    }
                    #endregion 

                }
```

Comment: Could you please simplify your example to make it possible to actually reproduce the issue locally? Like if you remove all the code from the imgProcessing method after the faulty line - will you still be able to reproduce the issue? And what if you don't load your bitmaps from your disk, but create a bunch of them dynamically?

Comment: What happens if the file is empty? The Bitmap(string) constructor only specifies an exception for file not found.

Comment: BTW you have a bottleneck I believe. Bitmap(string) constructor blocks for I/O, so you are only reading one file at a time, waiting for I/O, launching a thread then proceeding to the next iteration of the loop. Why don't you pass the filename to the thread and have the thread initiate the I/O so that the loop doesn't block?

Comment: chris rollins - thanks for the heads up about the bottleneck, but I didnt fully understand what does "blocks for I/O" means.  If I pass the thread the filename and create a bitmap in imgprocessing wouldn't it cuase a read violation ?

Comment: Should only be a problem if they are attempting to read the same file. However if I remember correctly, GDI (which is what System.Drawing uses) does not allow multiple threads to read/write on the same bitmap object anyway.

Comment: But anyway I mean that the constructor for Bitmap blocks the current thread until it loads the data from the file.

Comment: Just want to add a word about using Thread.... I seldom use Thread as initiating thread is **Super Expensive**, while you are creating thousands of threads for thousands of files, this is terrifying. DotNet does the thread management much better than human, use `Parallel.ForEach` or `Task`, they are easier to use and safer.

Comment: MatrixTai, I have asked in the pass my teachers whether or not I shoudl use task, but I always got the negative answer followed by the reccomndation of avoiding it because they are not as popular and easy to work with as threads.

Comment: Chris Rollins thank you, after reading both of your explanations I understood what you meant - let each individual thread handle the I/O to load rather than block the main loop and therefore the iteration while doing it.

Comment: @MatrixTai is right. Launching a new Thread object has non-trivial overhead. The Task class abstracts over the ThreadPool class, which already has a bunch of background threads that it delegates the work to. This is kind of a hairy subject but I believe if you want to make this as efficient as possible you should limit the concurrency to the value of Environment.ProccessorCount. You can do that with the ThreadPool class.

Comment: I can't believe `Task` is still not popular in recent days.... However I understand why your teacher prefer `Thread`. `Thread` is more fundamental, `Task` and other method is abstract, passing the control to computer. You can make your own `Task` class if you can deeply understand `Thread`. However, in modern development, no, avoid using `Thread` for easy task, you are no longer cleverer than computer.

Comment: Why are you calling the `Bitmap` constructor again on the passed parameter? Not sure I see the use of that; it doesn't seem to be used to unlock the loaded file or anything like that. Just cast it back to `Bitmap`.